# Count, compare and aggregate a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks as follows:

```
ID  my_val db_val
a       X       X
a       X       X
a       Y       X
b       X       Y
b       Y       Y
b       Y       Y
c       Z       X
c       X       X
c       Z       X
```

Expected result :

```
ID  my_val  db          match
 a  X:2;Y:1  X     full_match
 b  Y:2;X:1  Y     full_match
 c  z:2;X:1  X  partial_match
```

a full_match is when db_val matches the most abundant my_val
a partial_match is when db_val is in the other values but doesn't match the top one.

My current approach consists of grouping by ID then counting values into a seperate column then concatenating the value and its count, then aggregating all values into one row for each ID.

This is how I aggregate the columns:

```
def all_hits_aggregate_df(df, columns=['my_val']):
    grouped = data.groupby('ID')
    l=[]
    for c in columns:
        res = grouped[c].value_counts(ascending=False, normalize=False).to_frame('count_'+c).reset_index(level=1)
        res[c] = res[c].astype(str) +':'+ res['count_'+c].astype(str)
        l.append(res.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: ';'.join(x)))
    return reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'ID'), l)
```

And for the comparison phase, I loop through each row and parse the my_val column into lists then do the comparison.

I am sure that the way I do the comparison step is extremely inefficient but I am unsure how I would do it before aggregation to avoid having to parse the generated string later in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `groupby` the DataFrame by ID, then count `my_val` values with `value_counts` and convert to json with `to_json`, which, with some small changes in formatting, gives us the format that was requested (we just need to remove curly brackets and quotes and replace commas with semicolons). On the grouped data we also take the `first` (and presumably the only one per `ID`) value of `db_val` and calculate the percentage of matches (more than 50% will give us `full_match`, 0-50% is `partial_match` and 0% is `no_match`):

```
df['match'] = df['my_val']==df['db_val']

z = (df
     .groupby('ID')
     .agg({'my_val': lambda x: x.value_counts().to_json(),
          'db_val': 'first',
          'match': 'mean'})
    ).reset_index()

z['my_val'] = z['my_val'].str.replace('[{"}]','').str.replace(',',';')
z['match'] = np.select(
    [z['match'] > 0.5, z['match'] > 0],
    ['full_match', 'partial_match'], 'no_match')

print(z)
```

Output:

```
  ID   my_val db_val          match
0  a  X:2;Y:1      X     full_match
1  b  Y:2;X:1      Y     full_match
2  c  Z:2;X:1      X  partial_match
```

Comment: Thank you for this ! I have one question: I am doing this process to multiple columns; is there a way to dynamically name `.assign(match = df['my_val']==df['db_val'])` the column name for `assign()`?

Comment: Not in `assign` itself, but we can of course rename it later, for example when we replace the values in `z['match'] = np.select(...` we can save it as a new column `z['match_my_val_1'] = np.select(...`

Comment: Or, alternatively, we can pre-set the 'match' columns before this whole block with `df['match1'] = df['my_val1']==df['db_val1']`, `df['match2'] = df['my_val2']==df['db_val2']` etc. and then we can add `match1` and `match2` in our `agg` call with `.agg{..., 'match1': 'mean', 'match2': 'mean'}`

Comment: I've updated my answer with the latter option. With this you can name columns dynamically using `df[col_name] = ...` where `col_name` is a string variable with the column name. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the first part of what you want:

```
df['equal'] = df.my_val == df.db_val

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['my_val'] = df.groupby('ID')['my_val'].sum()
df2['db'] = df.groupby('ID')['db_val'].unique()

df2['match_val'] = df.groupby('ID')['equal'].sum()
df2['match'] = ''
df2.loc[df2.match_val/len(df2.my_val) > 0.5, 'match'] = 'full_match'
df2.loc[df2.match_val/len(df2.my_val) <= 0.5, 'match'] = 'partial_match'
df2.loc[df2.match_val/len(df2.my_val) == 0, 'match'] = 'no_match'
df2 = df2.drop(columns = 'match_val')

print(df2)
```

```
   my_val   db          match
ID                           
a     XXY  [X]     full_match
b     XYY  [Y]     full_match
c     ZXZ  [X]  partial_match
```

Comment: I miscommunicated the information, it's my bad. The `my_val` needs to preserve the count value. so `XXY` should be `X:2;Y:1`